# I want to add category slug in posts url

Tags: posts

I want to add category name or slug in the post url. I have tried by changing the permalink structure but it didn't work. Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: [https://helloapk.net/dls-23-mod-apk/](https://helloapk.net/dls-23-mod-apk/)

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. The solution given below worked perfectly. I have applied it on my new website too https://threads-downloader.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to permalink settings and select "Custom Structure" option listed on end. Then write `/%category%/%postname%/`. Save changes and now your post url will have category name too.